# Heteroscedasticity and Serial Correlation in FGLS model

Tags: panel-data, heteroscedasticity, fixed-effects-model, plm

I am currently working with panel data. My fixed effects model showed signs for serial correlation, cross sectional dependence and heteroscedasticity. Therefore, I continued with the FGLS method to account for these problems. However, when tested this model again pointed towards heteroscedasticity and serial correlation.

Are there further ways to treat these problems? In my understanding, the FGLS method is usually used to treat them, so now I don't really know how to proceed.

Is it possible to, for example, calculate robust standard errors?
Or are there possibilities to treat these problems in the fixed effects model.

I am working with the `plm` package in `R` and ran the FGLS regression with the `pggls` command. I am thankful for any recommendations and can also provide further information or code if necessary.